# Max allowed length (65535) of varchar column in Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, varchar

I have a table from which I need to pull information, and there is a column that for some records is causing Redshift to give me the below error.

```
Query 1 ERROR: ERROR:  Value of VARCHAR type is too long.
DETAIL:  
  -----------------------------------------------
  error:  Value of VARCHAR type is too long.
  code:      25101
  context:   Received VARCHAR len=75187 max=65535. This could be due to multibyte characters exceeding the column size or the value in remote database is larger than the max allowed length (65535) of varchar column in Redshift.
  query:     85267890
  location:  federation_fetchers.hpp:146
  process:   query1_122_85267890 [pid=9420]
  -----------------------------------------------
```

I have tried filtering the records in where clause beforehand, and it worked.

```
select *
   from table t
where len(t.my_column) < 65535
```

But I need to retrieve all the records in the table but it is throwing this error

I also tried splitting the column with `substring(t.my_column,1,65534)` but the error continues.

What can I do to be able to retrieve all the records even the ones with `length >= 65535`?

Comment: why not change the datatype to text?

Comment: It sounds very reasonable to me, but I'm only a user of that table with no permission to modify. Actually, I was wondering if there is a work around without making modifications to the table.

Comment: have you tried to cast it as text in the query?

Comment: I notice that the query is using 'federation'. From where is this data being obtained? I presume this is an external table from Redshift Spectrum?

Answer (score 2):

I'm curious as to how you got such a long value in a Redshift table.  I'm assuming that this is a spectrum (S3) table or some similar external table.  Is this correct?

This would make sense (external table) as the where clause would be applied externally and these values wouldn't be sent to Redshift.

As to your situation/issue.  I'll go with the assumption that this is a spectrum table until I hear otherwise.  S3 (Spectrum engine) will perform string functions which is why your WHERE clause query works - the values that are too long are not sent to Redshift.  See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c-spectrum-external-performance.html

I believe that substring() should also be performed in the S3/Spectrum domain per the docs.  This would imply that your second query should have worked as well which it didn't.  However, I think you may be running into the differences in how S3 and Redshift store character data (speculation).  Redshift stores characters in multi-byte UTF8 format and the length of a varchar is the number of bytes in the string, not the number of characters.  (The error message even hints as this.)  So you may need to limit the substring down further for Redshift to read it.

One way to see if this is the case is to compare the error message of the first query with the 3rd query.  In your original errors indicates "len=75187" - does having the substring function reduce this length down?  Is the string value just a few bytes too long with the substring() function?  If so then this might be the right track and the substring() is being applied externally to Redshift.

Redshift support the function octet_length() which returns the length in UFT-8 bytes of the string instead of character length.  Since the number of "extra bytes" needed for each string will be different it would be nice to have a programatic way to find the right max substring() length for each.  You can do this be subtracting the difference between octet_length() and length() from 65535.  Like:

```
substring(t.my_column,1,65534 - (octet_length(t.my_column) - length(t.my_column)))
```

Of course all of this is just theory since I don't know the actual location of the source table nor have complete confidence that all string functions are actually being applied in the S3 layer.  But a possibility.